# Does lombok project support openjdk 11?

Tags: java, lombok

Does lombok project support openjdk 11? If yes, How? I gave a try on it but couldn't.

Comment: Take a closer look at the Lombok's changelog https://projectlombok.org/changelog

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its not specifically mentioned in changelog but I think it is.

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't"?

Answer (score 0):

It supports, I used gradle 4.10 and then edited build.gradle to have the lombok imports as in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51874776/3022728)